# Rust -- How to handle error precisely and gracefully?

Tags: error-handling, rust

Sorry for naming this a so ambiguous title, but I can't come up with a better one.

The `read_dir()` method defined in `std::fs` returns instances of `io::Result<DirEntry>`, which is the alias of `Result<DirEntry, io::Error>`. When the caller does not exist on file system, it returns the error.

Now my code is

```rust
dir_a.read_dir();
dir_b.read_dir();
dir_c.read_dir();
```

And `dir_a`, `dir_b`, `dir_c` all may not exist. So these three statements may return the same `io::Error`, but for my program, `dir_a`, `dir_b` and `dir_c` have different meaning, where I want to handle the error for each one respectively.

So I defined my own enum `MyError` as

```rust
enum MyError {
    Dir_a_not_exist,
    Dir_b_not_exist,
    Dir_c_not_exist,
}
```

How can I transform the same `io::Error` to my different three `MyError`?

My ugly way is to

```rust
match dir_a.read_dir() {
    Ok => match dir_b.read_dir() {
              Ok => match dir_c.read_dir() {
                        Ok => { /* do something */ },
                        Err => return MyError::Dir_c_not_exist,
                    },
              Err => return MyError::Dir_b_not_exist,
          },
    Err => return MyError::Dir_a_not_exist,
};
```

Is there any graceful way I can handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Result` has a function called `or`, that allows you to forward the result if it's Ok, or transform it if it's an error. With that, you can do something like this:

```
fn foo(dir_a: &Path, dir_b: &Path, dir_c: &Path) -> Result<(), MyError> {
    dir_a.read_dir().or(Err(MyError::DirAnotExist))?;
    dir_b.read_dir().or(Err(MyError::DirBnotExist))?;
    dir_c.read_dir().or(Err(MyError::DirCnotExist))?;

    /* do something */

    Ok(())
}
```